# Are there third party Facebook clients?

Tags: facebook

I want to access Facebook without logging into facebook.com. Are there third-party Facebook clients (web-based) in which we can view posts, comments, etc and like and comment in them?

Comment: I personally don't do it due to security concerns. Be sure to use a trusted software/service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seesmic Web](https://seesmic.com/seesmic-social/desktop/) can do it.

Comment: Thanks. Also found that using this iGoogle gadget is easier. http://www.google.com/ig/directory?dpos=top&root=/ig&url=hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100080069921643878012/facebook.xml